# Recyclerview is not displaying Pre-Populated item on first run

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, sqliteopenhelper

I has pre populated the database by using addCallback function on Room.databaseBuilder. But the recyclerview doesn't display the item on the first run but it displays all the item correctly on second run. I am not able to understand what is the error? Any help would be helpful.

[App screen on the first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8zjG.jpg)

[App screen on second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgVUD.jpg)

Database Code:

```
@Database(entities = [Customer::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class CustomerDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract val customerDao: CustomerDao

companion object {

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: CustomerDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): CustomerDatabase =
        INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
                INSTANCE = it
            }
        }

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        CustomerDatabase::class.java,
        "customer_database",
    ).addCallback(object : Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            ioThread {
                getInstance(context).customerDao.insertCustomer(PREPOPULATE_DATA)
            }
        }
    }).build()

    

    val PREPOPULATE_DATA = listOf<Customer>(
        customer1,
        customer2,
        customer3,
        customer4,
        customer5,
        customer6,
        customer7,
        customer8,
        customer9,
        customer10,
        customer11
    )
  }
}
```

Dao Interface:

```
@Dao
interface CustomerDao {

 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 fun insertCustomer(customerList: List<Customer>)

 @Query("SELECT * FROM customer_table")
 suspend fun getAllCustomer(): List<Customer>
}
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "customer_table")
data class Customer constructor(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Int = 0,
  val customerName: String,
  val customerEmail: String,
  val customerMobileNumber: String,
  val customerAccountNumber: String,
  val ifscCode: String,
  val accountBalance: Int
)
```

CustomerFragment Code:

```
class CustomerFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentCustomerBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: CustomerViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentCustomerBinding.inflate(inflater)

    val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
    val dataSource = 
CustomerDatabase.getInstance(application).customerDao
    val viewModelFactory = CustomerViewModelFactory(dataSource)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, 
viewModelFactory).get(CustomerViewModel::class.java)

    val adapter = CustomerAdapter(CustomerItemClickListener { customer ->
        Toast.makeText(
            activity?.applicationContext,
            "Selected customer is ${customer.customerName}",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    })

    binding.customerRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.customerList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { customerList ->
        customerList.let {
            adapter.submitList(customerList)
        }
    })

    binding.viewmodel = viewModel
    return binding.root
 }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
class CustomerViewModel(private val datasource: CustomerDao) : ViewModel() {

private val _customerList = MutableLiveData<List<Customer>>()
val customerList: LiveData<List<Customer>>
    get() = _customerList


init {
    getCustomerList()
}

private fun getCustomerList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _customerList.value = datasource.getAllCustomer()
    }
 }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class CustomerAdapter(val clickListener: CustomerItemClickListener) :
ListAdapter<Customer, CustomerAdapter.CustomerViewHolder>(DiffCallBack) {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomerViewHolder {
    return CustomerViewHolder(
        CustomerItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position), clickListener)
}


companion object DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Customer>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Customer, newItem: Customer): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Customer, newItem: Customer): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}


class CustomerViewHolder(private var binding: CustomerItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(customer: Customer, clickListener: CustomerItemClickListener) {
        binding.customer = customer
        binding.clicklistener = clickListener
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
 }
}

class CustomerItemClickListener(val clickListener: (customer: Customer) -> Unit) {
  fun onClick(customer: Customer) = clickListener(customer)
}
```

Executors:

```
private val IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

/**
* Utility method to run blocks on a dedicated background thread, used for io/database work.
*/
fun ioThread(f: () -> Unit) {
  IO_EXECUTOR.execute(f)
}
```

Customer item:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="customer"
        type="com.itsamankrsingh.basicbankingapp.database.Customer" />

    <variable
        name="clicklistener"
        
   type="com.itsamankrsingh.basicbankingapp.ui.fragment.customer.CustomerItemClickListener" />

</data>


<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:onClick="@{()->clicklistener.onClick(customer)}"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:contentPadding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circular_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/customer_name_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@{customer.customerName}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linear_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Aman Kumar Singh" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_account_number_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@{customer.customerAccountNumber}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linear_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/customer_name_tv"
            tools:text="0123456789" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please add the code for dao. I am pretty sure that this is happening because adding data to the db is an async task which means that, when you're fetching the data in the UI in the first run, at that time the data hasn't been added in the db hence the empty list but by the second attempt data has been added and hence it is being displayed. To resolve this issue, return Flow from the db(in dao) i.e fun getAllCustomers(): Flow<List<Customer>>, and subscribe to the response in the VM. Once all the items are added in the list, it will be collected by VM and then the recyclerView will be updated.

Comment: I have added the code for dao. I tried to implement the above solution but it was not working.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine for me as it should, I am not sure why it isn't working for you. One thing that I noticed is that, when you want a context, use either `this`, and `requireContext()`.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved after I changed the return type from List<Customer> to LiveData<List<Customer>>

Comment: Mine worked without LiveData, anyway you should use Flow instead of LiveData, and Live Data should only be used in View(Activity/Fragment). There are many articles that explain why you should do so.